# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading : 'productName')

Tags: sql, express, select, insert

I'm encountering a problem when I pass a selectedProductName eg. 'Black Jacket (M)', to my next query. The selectedProductName should get productName from the product table and with that, I'll use that to get the productID to be inserted to my orders table since the productID is a foreign key in my orders table. If you wonder, my front end creates a new customer. It also adds the information for the new order.

This is the whole app.js query for reference

```
app.post("/create", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("Request Body:", req.body);

try {
const {
  quantity,
  orderStatus,
  custName,
  contactInfo,
  location,
  selectedProductName,
} = req.body;

console.log("Selected Product Name:", selectedProductName);
 
// Insert customer first
const insertCustomerQuery = `
  INSERT INTO customer (customerName, contactInformation, location)
  VALUES (?, ?, ?)
`;
const customerResult = await db.query(insertCustomerQuery, [
  custName,
  contactInfo,
  location,
]);
const customerId = customerResult.insertId;

// Get the product name from the selected product
const getProductQuery = `
  SELECT productName FROM product WHERE productName = ?
`;

console.log("Product Name Query:", getProductQuery);

const productNameResult = await db.query(getProductQuery, [
  selectedProductName,
]);
const productName = productNameResult[0].productName;

// Get product ID based on the obtained product name
const getProductIDQuery = `
  SELECT productID FROM product WHERE productName = ?
`;

console.log("Product ID Query:", getProductIDQuery);

const productIDResult = await db.query(getProductIDQuery, [
  productName,
]);
const productID = productIDResult[0].productID;

console.log("Product ID Result:", productIDResult);

// Insert order using the obtained customer ID and product ID
const insertOrderQuery = `
  INSERT INTO orders (orderStatus, orderQuantity, orderDate, productID, customerID)
  VALUES (?, ?, NOW(), ?, ?)
`;
await db.query(insertOrderQuery, [
  orderStatus,
  quantity,
  productID,
  customerId,
]);

res.send("Order created successfully!");
} catch (err) {
console.log(err);
res.status(500).send("Error creating order");
}
});`
```

it says that

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'productName')

I've tried getting the productID instead of the productName yet the error is still the same. It      would say it cannot read properties of undefined which is the productID.

Comment: At a glance it sounds like `SELECT productName FROM product WHERE productName = ?` didn't return any results.  Though it's not clear what that query is meant to accomplish in the first place.  You're trying to select the exact value that you already have.

Comment: I've tried using gathering the productID instead of the productName yet it still returns the same error.

SELECT productID from product WHERE productName = ?

it still says that productID is undefined

Comment: Probably the same issue... It's not finding any matching record.  When you debug, what is `selectedProductName`?  What exact record(s) in the database are you expecting it to return?

Comment: this is what the console.log returns

selectedProductName: 'Black Jacket (M)'
}
Selected Product Name: Black Jacket (M)
product ID:
      SELECT productID FROM product WHERE productName = ?

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'productID')

Comment: And are there any records in the database which exactly match that value?  How specifically have you confirmed this?

Comment: Yes there is. That's why I'm also confused on why that error keeps on showing even though I have the exact same value in my database.

Comment: Perhaps the value isn't *exact*, and either the supplied value or the value in the database has some additional whitespace?  As a debugging step, try selecting all records and looping over them to find the matching record in the code, do the values match exactly?